# "The printer is exposed to strong light" error on Epson XP-640

Tags: inkjet-printer

I performed a deep clean on my Epson XP-640 printer (forcing cleaner through the heads, with a paper towel under the heads), and when I was done I replaced the ink cartridges. When I turned the unit on again, it gave me an error message that "The printer is exposed to strong light". Google returns only a handful of hits on this error. Any ideas?

Comment: I regret to inform you that your printer has become a vampire. You may resolve the issue by finding the lead printer and driving a stake through its ink or toner cartridge, or destroying it with fire.

Comment: Does the scanner have enough ink?

Comment: I was tempted to prescribe Detly's vampire treatment but first, how is such a specific error message an issue for SuperUser rather than printers in general or Epson in particular?

Comment: Ink was not an issue.  As for why it's here in SuperUser, I was told this was the best stack for this issue.  I just wanted it documented, because I found several questions and not many useable answers.  My answer is an option for users to try, it worked for me.

Comment: "Google returns only a handful of hits..." While this may seem pointless given you've found a solution and posted it, but perhaps for future reference, when you tell this site you've searched the web, we expect you to have tried some things AND tell us what those things are that you tried, as part of the question. This reads like "I spent a moment and didn't find anything obvious but didn't think too hard about it. I want you all to spend your time and effort to solve this problem I didn't feel like spending my own time and effort to solve."

Comment: @music2myear - This was more of an "Ask a question and immediately answer it yourself", which SE encourages you to do.  In fact, right after you ask a question it literally asks you if you want to answer it yourself.  SE, as I understand it, is more concerned about sharing information than "scoring points", if you believe I'm in error I'd encourage you to ask for clarity on Meta SE.

Answer (score 40):

I was able to fix this issue using one of these methods, but I'm going to put them both here for anyone who has this issue in the future.

1. Make sure the scanner unit lid is fully pressing the closure indicator button. If it's not, the sensor will think the lid is still open.
2. Turn the printer off and wait overnight. There may be some moisture from cleaning, and it needs time to dry.

I used #2, and in the morning the printer turned on and worked as normal.

Comment: Perhaps some dropelets on light sensors acted as lenses.